# Is there any issue while developing rails app with Ubuntu OS and Deploying using Windows or vice versa?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-ec2, ruby-on-rails-3.2

My case is like I want work already deployed application to Windows and I wanna work in my local system with Ubuntu so there is any problem doing so.

welcome and thanks any one who can give details Answer on this question.

Comment: If you are using mysql, good luck with setting mysql2 adaptor on windows. This question is way to broad, it depends on the deployment process, server structure etc. If deployment script is correct, then there should be no bigger issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a wide question, I can tell you what works for me, if it helps.

I develop on windows 8.1, and deploy to Ubuntu.
I use Capistrano 3 and a private git repository.
Deploying to Nginx, passenger and MariaDB.
Ubuntu is setup with a deploy user, and a local rvm.
Latest Ruby and Rails.

mysql2 compilation takes a little work on windows, and then bundle install on production breaks. as the Gemfile.lock is set to the windows version, I have to use the --no-deployment option when bundle installing. Some folks do something a bit more clever.

I have not gotten ssh agent forwarding working, so I have a private key for my deploy user on the production machine, without password, to fetch (in Capistrano 2 I used deploy :copy). I haven't really tried to fix it to be fair.

There are plenty of answers to these issues on stack overflow. I can't think of anything else that really hurt. No show stoppers so far.

Comment: My case is like I want work already deployed application to Windows and I wanna work in my local system with Ubuntu so there is any problem doing so.